# How to update an sqlite3 database every 30 seconds from an express server using an external api

Tags: node.js, http, backend, setinterval, node-sqlite3

I'm making a website which tracks kill statistics in a game but I can only access 50 key value pairs per request, so to make sure that my data is accurate I want to make a request about every 30 seconds.

I feel like I may have gone wrong at some stage in the implementation. Like, maybe there is a way to make requests that doesn't involve using
`express.get('/route/', (req, res) => { //code })`
syntax and I just don't know about it. In short, what I want is for the database to be updated every 30 seconds without having to refresh the browser. I've tried wrapping my get request in a function and putting it in set interval but it still doesn't run.

```
const express = require('express');
const zkillRouter = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const zkillDbInit = require('../utils/zkillTableInit');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

zkillDbInit();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('zkill.db');

setInterval(() => {
    zkillRouter.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        axios.get('https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/w-space/', {headers: {
            'accept-encoding':'gzip',
            'user-agent': 'me',
            'connection': 'close'
        }})
            .then(response => {
            // handle success
                const wormholeData = (response.data)
                res.status(200);
                //probably not the best way to do this but it's fine for now.
                for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(wormholeData).length; i++) {
                    const currentZKillId = Object.keys(wormholeData)[i]
                    const currentHash = Object.values(wormholeData)[i]
                    let values = {
                        $zkill_id: currentZKillId,
                        $hash: currentHash
                    };
                    //puts it in the database
                    db.run(`INSERT INTO zkill (zkill_id, hash) VALUES ($zkill_id, $hash)`,
                    values
                    , function(err){
                        if(err){
                            throw(err)
                        }
                    })
                }
        })
    })
}, 1000)

module.exports = zkillRouter;
```

One thing I have considered is that I don't necessarily need this functionality to be part of the same program. All I need is the database, so if I have to I could run this code separately in say, the terminal as just a little node program that makes requests to the api and updates the database. I don't think that would be ideal but if it's the only way to do what I want then I'll consider it.

clarification: the `.get()` method is called on zkillRouter which is an instance of express.Router() declared on line two. This in turn links back to my app.js file through an apiRouter, so the full route is localhost:5000/api/zkill/. That was a big part of the problem, I didn't know you could call axios.get without specifying a route, so I was stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify.  What invokes the `.get()` route method you defined in your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself.

(edit 4)

1. I was using setInterval wrong.
2. I just got rid of the router statement as it wasn't needed.
3. I definitely need to tweak the interval so that I don't get so many sql errors for violating the unique constraint. Every 5 minutes should be enough I think.
4. Don't throw an error.

```
function myfunction(){
        axios.get('https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/w-space/', {headers: {
            'accept-encoding':'gzip',
            'user-agent': 'me lol',
            'connection': 'close'
        }})
            .then(response => {
            // handle success
                const wormholeData = (response.data)
                for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(wormholeData).length; i++) {
                    const currentZKillId = Object.keys(wormholeData)[i]
                    const currentHash = Object.values(wormholeData)[i]
                    let values = {
                        $zkill_id: currentZKillId,
                        $hash: currentHash
                    };
                    db.run(`INSERT INTO zkill (zkill_id, hash) VALUES ($zkill_id, $hash)`,
                    values
                    , function(err){
                        if(err){
                            return console.log(i);
                        }
                    })
                }
        })
}

setInterval(myfunction, 1000 * 30)
```